# .ajax, jquery, images that load late after upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use .ajax jquery to upload images, but the images are still being uploaded when ajax finishes. The load event that is called after loads the same images. I have to refresh a few times before I get the right image.

I tried using setTimeout but it did not work. How can I fix this problem?

ADDED: As you can see, I tried using a timeout but it didn't work

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url:"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>",
            type:"POST",
            data:X,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            beforeSend:function()
            { 
                $('#MAIN').animate({opacity:0.2}); 
                $('#LOADING').fadeIn(250);
            },
            success:function()
            {
                setTimeout(function()
                { 
                    $('#'+Y+'_LOAD').load('FRAME/image.php',{USER_CODE:Z,TYPE:Y},function()
                    {
                        $('#MAIN').animate({opacity:1});
                        $('#LOADING').fadeOut(250);

                        HEIGHT = $('#'+Y+'_LOAD').show().height(); 

                        $('#'+Y+'_SLIDE').animate({'height':HEIGHT-3},function()
                        {
                            $('#'+Y+'_LOAD').fadeIn(150);
                        });
                    });
                },5000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: We need to see some code. "I use .ajax to upload images" sounds a bit impossible so we need to see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Where are X and Y defined?

Comment: Yes, X is form data, Y is the image form identification. Don't worry about those things. My problem is that after upload, it loads the data, but its the old image. It takes about a few seconds for the new one to be uploaded. I have to refresh to get it

Comment: I need the load to contain new image.

Comment: But if you refresh, the upload would be cancelled. How could it still work after a refresh?

Comment: I know, there must be some old stored data still existent. Do browsers store old data for images? can it be cleared

Comment: There must be some kind of cache data from old image. Can this be cleared?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is no-cache the image or create something like this:

```
BANNER.jpg?V='.time();
```

BUT when using background image, it does not find the image. Anyone have a solution that, please post.